# Upload csv dataset in XAMPP

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I want to upload a csv file in Xampp. The basic structure of my data is:

```
"age";"job";"marital";"education";"default";"housing";"loan";"contact";"month";"day_of_week";"duration";"campaign";"pdays";"previous";"poutcome";"emp.var.rate";"cons.price.idx";"cons.conf.idx";"euribor3m";"nr.employed";"y"
 56;"housemaid";"married";"basic.4y";"no";"no";"no";"telephone";"may";"mon";261;1;999;0;"nonexistent";1.1;93.994;-36.4;4.857;5191;"no"
 57;"services";"married";"high.school";"unknown";"no";"no";"telephone";"may";"mon";149;1;999;0;"nonexistent";1.1;93.994;-36.4;4.857;5191;"no"
```

Before upload i filled up the basic data requirements, where it was:

```
 Enable foreign key check
 Columns separated with:    ;
 Columns enclosed with:
 Columns escaped with:
 Lines terminated with:    auto
```

But after upload my dataset, it only showed the COL1, COL 2, ...... i couldn't find my column name and data also. How can i upload this data?

Answer (score 0):

First, I created a database but did not create a table in it. Next, I tried the import using your example file and most of the settings you've listed; I've also checked the box for "The first line of the file contains the table column names *(if this is unchecked, the first line will become part of the data)*" and used a double-quote `"` for "Columns enclosed with:"

[image: Import settings5]

It worked as I expected:

[image: Import successful]

What results are you seeing? Which phpMyAdmin version (I tested this with the latest 4.7.9).